# iterate through a a set of input nested into groups and sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, iteration

I want to iterate through a a set of input nested into groups and sections, 
with the goal of performaing validation within each group and section

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<div  id="groupA" class="preGroups">

    <div id="section-A1">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
    <input name="SRPR2"  type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="section-A2">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
    <input name="SRPR2"  type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="section-A3">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
    <input name="SRPR2"  type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="section-A4">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
    <input name="SRPR2"  type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div  id="groupB" class="preGroups">

    <div id="section-B1">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
    <input name="SRPR2"  type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="section-B2">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
    <input name="SRPR2"  type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="section-B3">
    <input name="SRPR1"  type="text">
    <input name="SRPR2"  type="text">
    </div>
    </div>
<script>    

// capture all groups
groups = $('div#[id^=group]'); 
console.log(groups);

// iterate through each group in groups
$.each(groups, function(key, group) {
    console.log(group);

    // iterate through each section in group 
    sections = $('div#[id^=section]'); 
    $.each(sections, function(key, section) {
        console.log(section);

        // iterate inputs in each group
        // more code goes here
        /// console.log(input.name + " " +  input.value);       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might need `sections = $(group).find('div#[id^=section]');` instead of `sections = $('div#[id^=section]');`

### EDIT

complete code here:

```
groups = $('div[id^="group"]'); 
//console.log(groups);

// iterate through each group in groups
$.each(groups, function(key, group) {
    //console.log(group);

    // iterate through each section in group 
    sections = $(group).find('div[id^="section"]'); 
    $.each(sections, function(key, section) {
        //console.log(section);
        var inputs = $(section).find("input");
        // iterate inputs in each group
        // more code goes here
        inputs.each(function(){
            console.log(this.name + " " +  this.value);
        })
        /// console.log(input.name + " " +  input.value);       
    });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hNkPk/)

Comment: in `$('div#[id^=group]');` the `#` isn't required, just `$('div[id^="group"]');` would work, and note that quoting attribute values is ***mandatory***, according to the [API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Good catch. I just copy and pasted the PO's code, but it should be amended.  I'll fix it in my code here on SO but probably leave the example mostly as is